# SharedPreference not available after app restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to figure out why I can't have access to my SharedPreference file after an app restart.

In my Application class in the onCreate I define my SharedPreference once :

```
pref = getSharedPreferences(Util.PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
```

And then in the onResume of my activity I call:

```
String userName = MyApp.getApplication().pref.getString(Util.USER_NAME, "");
```

But at this point the user name is always empty after a restart.

-To save my value :

```
MyApp.getApplication().editor.putString(Util.USER_NAME,"name").commit();
```

-For MyApp.getApplication() I've defined in my Application class:

```
public MyApp() {
     instance = this;
}
public static MyApp getApplication() {
     if (instance == null) {
         instance = new MyApp();
     }
     return instance;
}
```

From my device I run a terminal app and with a 'cat' command  I can see the content of my sharedPreference XML file. Even when I kill my app I can see the sharedPreference file is still there with my correct value inside. 
But when I restart my app this value can't be read. What is happening there ?

I've noticed on a tablet with android Lollipop I've no problem but with a tablet with android Kitkat I have this problem.

Comment: You have to commit the editor . `editor.commit();`

Comment: @ZahidulIslam it's what I've done with MyApp.getApplication().editor.putString(Util.USER_NAME,"name").commit(); ?

Comment: Any chance Util.PREF_FILE_NAME changes value on app lunch?

Comment: Util.PREF_FILE_NAME the value is never changed.

Answer (score 0):

Interface used for modifying values in a SharedPreferences object. All changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()

So Dont forget to your `editor.commit()`

Comment: he has .commit() after the change

Answer (score -1):

**Best Way which I using :**

> Util.class

```
public static void saveIntToUserDefaults(Context c, String Key, int value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = c.getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(Key, value);
    editor.commit();
    Log.e("Saved:", "" + Key + "-" + value);
}

public static String getFromUserDefaults(Context c, String Key) {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = c.getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return sharedpreferences.getString(Key, "");
}

public static void clearUserDefaults(Context c) {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = c.getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

**I calling this wherever I need & its working superb**